# How to set VBA to auto-update filter criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

Everyday I receive .xls file with changing date and time. How could I make macro that always filters last dateTime from pivot table?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Sub Choose_the_last_item()
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DATE").ClearAllFilters
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DATE").PivotItems.Count - 1
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DATE").PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Change `PivotTable1` to your Pivot name, and `DATE` to your Date field name.

Comment: I think this loops infinately...

Comment: why do you think? It worked for me